# Backup and Sync has encountered a fatal error, and will now terminate. Mid 2011 iMac - High Sierra

Tags: imac

I recently updated my 27in Mid 2011 iMac to a 1Tb SSD HD and to High Sierra. Now I don't have access to my Google drive :(

I've been looking everywhere and have found no solution to this. Can anyone help?

More details from the error:

"An uncaught exception was raised during execution of the main script.

This may mean that an unexpected error has occurred, or that you do not have all of the dependencies for this application.

See the Console for a detailed traceback."

Two errors I can see in the Console:

[ERROR] - Unknown CGXDisplayDevice: 0x41dc9d00

volume validation failed for <<(null)>>

Any ideas?

Comment: what "script" ? can you access Google drive online ?

Comment: "script" meaning just opening a fresh install of Backup & Sync. That's exactly what the error dialog displays. I can indeed open G drive online.

Comment: I suggest you install and run Analysis tool called EtreCheck then publish the report here. https://etrecheck.com/

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, with an iMac 27inches 2019 (MacOS Mojave 10.14.4). Any update on this?

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem, now solved. `~/Library/Application Support/Google` belongs to root. Either change privileges:

```
sudo chmod a+wx ~/Library/"Application Support"/Google
```

Or change owner:

```
sudo chown NameOfMyAccount ~/Library/"Application Support"/Google
```

Answer (score 5):

If Google Drive suddenly stopped working a week ago, you most probably updated to the latest version.

You can't install the latest Google Drive (version 3.50). Version 3.49 will work.

I fixed this on my Mac running El Capitan (I have to stay with this OS on my work computer because of the plugins I am using, my other Mac running the latest OS X has no problems with the latest Google Drive version.)

Follow these instructions (replace `<yourusername>` with your username):

1. Go to your Applications folder and delete "Backup and Sync" by moving it to your Trash.
2. Remove the `Drive` folder in `/User/<yourusername>/Library/Application Support/Google`.
3. Install "Backup and Sync" 3.49 (you can get it from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f1m5shqujac9ha7/InstallBackupAndSync%203.49.dmg?dl=0) by double clicking the downloaded file and dragging Backup and Sync to the Applications folder, **but don't launch it yet**.
4. As explained [in this post](https://medium.com/@danilosapad/how-to-fix-backup-and-sync-has-encountered-a-fatal-error-and-will-now-terminate-error-on-macos-a4b773b635c7):

   1. Open up the Terminal application in `/Applications/Utilities`.
   2. Type the following and hit the return key after you type each line for the command to go through (enter your administrator/user password if prompted to do so):

      ```
      cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google
      sudo mkdir -p Drive; sudo chmod 700 Drive;
      sudo chown <yourusername> Drive
      ```
5. You can now launch "Backup and Sync".

Owe me a cup of coffee!!

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to get these steps to work with the latest version of Backup And Sync, you don't necessarily need to get specifically v3.49

Comment: Is there a way to prevent Backup and Sync from auto-updating? Only then this can work for el Capitan, otherwise sooner or later the app will be updated again and will stop working, as it is not supporting anymore el Capitan.

Comment: this worked but i got a message "this version of backup and sync is no longer supported"
so i guess fix isn't valid anymore

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem after upgrading to Mac OSX Catalina. I had to do the following.

First, add a new folder named "Drive" in

> ~/Library/"Application Support"/Google

Second, I changed the rights to "Drive"

> sudo chmod a+wx ~/Library/"Application Support"/Google/Drive

Hope this helps